# Updating records using stored procedure .. in ASP.NET no access to the RowUpdating event

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm facing a problem with updating rows in SQL Server

When I want to update columns from a grid to a table in the SQL Server database using a stored procedure I have a problems with the `onclick` button (for the update). It will call a `RowUpdating` event ... the problem is there is no access to that event ... because I put a MsgBox in the first line .. nothing happened

This is the code :

asp .net code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="DossierGV" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
              AllowSorting="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              DataKeyNames="ID_Dossier" onrowupdating="DossierGV_RowUpdating" >
   <Columns>
      <%--       <asp:BoundField DataField="Nom_Giac" HeaderText="Nom_Giac" 
                          SortExpression="Nom_Giac" />--%>
      <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Modifier "></asp:CommandField>
      <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID_Dossier" SortExpression="ID_Dossier">
         <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID_Dossier") %>'></asp:Label>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID_Dossier") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID_Entreprise" SortExpression="ID_Entreprise">
         <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="ID_Entrepriselbl_Edit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID_Entreprise") %>'></asp:Label>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="ID_Entrepriselbl_Item" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID_Entreprise") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    ..... (lots more <asp:TemplateField) ..........
   </Columns>
   <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#F2E488" Font-Bold="True" />
```

and this is the server code :

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration

Partial Class GIAC_Gestion_des_dossiers_Les_Dossiers_Finance
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim sqlcon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("OfficeConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim dt1 As DataTable = New DataTable

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        RecherhcerComboBox.SelectedValue = RecherhcerComboBox.Items(0).Value
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            GridData()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub GridData()
        sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("DossierPF", sqlcon)
        sqlcon.Open()
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@nom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session("Nom_GIAC")
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd)
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            DossierGV.DataSource = dt
            DossierGV.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DossierGV_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DossierGV.SelectedIndexChanged
        GridData()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DossierGV_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles DossierGV.PageIndexChanging
        DossierGV.EditIndex = -1
        DossierGV.SelectedIndex = -1
        DossierGV.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        GridData()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DossierGV_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCancelEditEventArgs) Handles DossierGV.RowCancelingEdit
        DossierGV.EditIndex = -1
        GridData()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DossierGV_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles DossierGV.RowEditing
        DossierGV.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
        GridData()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DossierGV_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles DossierGV.RowUpdating
        MsgBox("walo")
        Dim row As GridViewRow = DossierGV.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        Dim ID_Dossier As Integer = DossierGV.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value
        Dim Montant_Demander As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("Montant_DemanderTXT"), TextBox)
        Dim Duree As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("DureeTXT"), TextBox)
        Dim Date_Debut As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("Date_DebutTXT"), TextBox)
        Dim Date_Fin As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("Date_FinTXT"), TextBox)

        sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE_DOSSIER", sqlcon)
        DossierGV.EditIndex = -1
        sqlcon.Open()
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ID_DOSSIER", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID_Dossier
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Montant_Demander", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt64(Montant_Demander.Text)
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@@Duree", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt64(Duree.Text)
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Date_Debut", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Date_Debut.Text)
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Date_Fin", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Date_Fin.Text)
        MsgBox(ID_Dossier & " , " & Montant_Demander.Text & " , " & Duree.Text & " , " & Date_Debut.Text & " , " & Date_Fin.Text)
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlcon.Close()

        GridData()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_DOSSIER 
 @ID_DOSSIER integer,
 @Montant_Demander integer,
 @Duree integer,
 @Date_Debut datetime,
 @Date_Fin datetime
AS 
BEGIN
   update dbo.Dossier
   set Montant_Demander = @Montant_Demander,
       Duree = @Duree,
       Date_Debut = @Date_Debut,
       Date_Fin = @Date_Fin
   where 
       ID_Dossier = @ID_DOSSIER
END

exec UPDATE_DOSSIER 1,400,5,'2007-01-11 00:00:00.000','2012-01-11 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: **Which** button do you click on to start the update??

Comment: removing msgbox allow the code to execute?

Comment: this one :   <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Modifier "></asp:CommandField>

Comment: @ImranRizvi no i'm just tasting by a msgbox